# Who am I? - A Historical Identity Riddle

Tags: riddle, knowledge, poetry

> I am a person known throughout the world,
>
> And yet my accomplishments that are remembered are like some cosmic joke.
>
> I change a piece of clothing just one time!
>
> And so I lost the war.
>
> My last battle,
>
> Why did it have to be named what it is?
>
> I feel like God is taunting me,
>
> From above his empire of love.
>
> I was never murdered,
>
> but I might as well have been.
>
> For my fate is the same regardless.
>
> I will never be the most atrocious person,
>
> as that title is saved for another.
>
> But I believe you should know now,
>
> Who am I?

*Explain every PART of the riddle (not every line) in your answer*

Comment: I do not think that I have enough knowledge to answer every part of the riddle, but is the person you are thinking of rot13(Orarqvpg Neabyq?)

Comment: @Bewilderer sadly not.

Comment: is this a historical figure or a mythical one?

Comment: @coffin_queen Historical. I changed the name of the riddle to that as well.

Comment: out of curiosity, was the word 'cosmic' in the second line a reference to something in particular? I get jokes about the country and person in general but that particular word seemed specific to me.

Comment: @coffin_queen That word was used mostly to apply to the "I feel like God is taunting me" part later used in the riddle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be:

> Napoleon Bonaparte:

> I am a person known throughout the world,
>
> And yet my accomplishments that are remembered are like some cosmic joke

> Despite conquering almost all of continental Europe, there are now a lot of jokes about the French surrendering. Also there are a lot of jokes about Napoleon's height (thanks Amoz!)

> I change a piece of clothing just one time!
>
> And so I lost the war.

> There is the hypothesis that a [change in buttons corresponded to Napoleon losing the war against Russia](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/smart-news/napoleons-army-may-have-suffered-from-the-greatest-wardrobe-malfunction-in-history-92535444/)

> My last battle,
>
> Why did it have to be named what it is?

> "Waterloo" has become synonymous with being defeated badly.

> I feel like God is taunting me,
>
> From above his empire of love.

> There is a book called [Empire Of Love](https://oxford.universitypressscholarship.com/view/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780195162950.001.0001/acprof-9780195162950) about the French Empire in the Pacific Ocean. Those colonies were established after Napoleon was deposed.

> I was never murdered,
>
> but I might as well have been.
>
> For my fate is the same regardless.

> He was exiled to St. Helena, where he couldn't affect change in the world until died. There were rumours that he was poisoned by arsenic, but it, [might have just been in the wallpaper](https://victorianweb.org/history/arsenic.html)

> I will never be the most atrocious person,
>
> as that title is saved for another.

> Napoleon's legacy is [highly controversial](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/history/article/napoleon-bonaparte-enlightened-leader-or-tyrant) and there are some who would call him a tyrant and dictator and render him personally responsible for the over 2 million dpeople who died during his conquests. However, there have been far worse people in history.

Comment: Nice! That was my guess but I couldn't for the life of me figure out the clothing line : )

Comment: damn, that's gotta be it. nice work!

Comment: I thought the 'joke' might be referring to all the jokes about their (urvtug)

Comment: the clothing line was what had me stumped as well. hadn't heard of that before

Comment: I got the clothing line by googling after I had already guessed the person.

Comment: @Amoz good point about the jokes! I've included it in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a far fetch, but I think you might be

> Lucifer the first fallen angel, better known as Satan. He stood up against God and lost the battle and was cast out of heaven (changing clothes only once from an angel to the devil). He feels like God is taunting him from heaven while he is in hell. He wasn't murdered, but is banned from heaven to rot in hell for all time.